# how to echo and filedownload together in php

Tags: php, download, echo

The following code is mine.

I want to download a file and echo together in Php. But echo in end of code doesn't work, how to fixed this code?

```
$filename = trim($conf['savedir']).$_GET['task'].".".$_GET['hash'].".xml";
$downname = $_GET['task'].'.'.$_GET['hash'].'.xml';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
if($fp == null)
{
    echo "Wrong Access1";
} else {
    header('Content-type:text/xml charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$downname);
    header('Content-length:'.filesize($filename));
    header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fpassthru($filename);
    fclose($fp);
    echo $_GET['task'].'.'.$_GET['hash'].'.xml file download.';
}
```

Comment: One http request can only give one response, either a file download, or an html output, not both.... this isn't a PHP problem, it's the way the web works

Comment: do you know why echo is writed in file?

Comment: yes I know why echo is writed in file; because you're sending both the file and the echoed message to the brower

Comment: thank you for your answer. Maybe do you know solution at this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mark Backer said, you can't echo and download at the same time for the same request, but there are some "tricks" to echo something and download the file.

Let's suppose that your code from the question is located into test.php file and the user requests the file that contains the code bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('test.php?task=<?=$_GET['task']?>&hash=<?=$_GET['hash']?>', '_blank');
</script>
<?php
echo $_GET['task'].'.'.$_GET['hash'].'.xml file download.';
```

So, the javascript code will pass the $_GET variables to test.php open a new window for download and in echo your message in the current window.

Comment: thank you for your solution. your solution prompt my idea. but substance of my code is not just download.

Comment: You're welcome! You can move the whole "if-else" instruction here and let only the functionality of download in "test.php", otherwise, if you echo something from download script, then all the output will be at the beginning or at the end of downloaded file.